# Can open-source LWCs be compiled into a single output file?

Tags: lightning-web-components

When I build an LWC in production mode I get two distinct files as output: 0.app.js and app.js. Is there any way to configure the compiler to produce a single file? This would simplify distribution.

Presumably one can just concatenate the files with gulp or similar, but if there's a way to do this without adding to the toolchain that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Process is called [Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) and is actually a best practice because it allows e.g. to load code fragments in parallel or to lazy load components at runtime. I don`t know what differences in terms of distribution it makes if you upload a folder with 3 files or 5 files to be honest especially compared with the benefits you may get with Code Splitting. If you still want to disable this optimization step you can pass in a custom webpack config via -w flag.

```
lwc-services build -m production -w webpack.config.js
```

And following content for webpack.config.js (which has to be in the same folder):

```
module.exports = {
    optimization: { splitChunks: false }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense, and I completely understand the optimization issues. What I'm trying to achieve is simplicity for people in my orgainization--many of whom are not Javascript savvy--dropping the component into web pages that aren't built with LWC. A single file and single script tag makes it harder to screw up.